# Reboot loop after sysprep of AD machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, sysprep

Major screw-up here and I need to find out how much trouble I am in.

I have an AD machine that is running Server 2008 R2, hyperv, DHCP and DNS. On the hyperv machine, I have a backup AD instance running along with a handfull of other server 2008 instances.

Sysprep was run on the hyperv machine instead of one of the instances.

I am attempting to bring the machine back up so I can try a system restore.

When I boot the hyperv machine, I get an error that says “Windows could not complete the installation. To install windows on this computer , restart the installation” This message occurs in safe mode, AD restore mode and in last known configuration mode.

[image]

How can I get my OS to boot at this point? Do I need to reinstall 2008 R2 from scratch?

Comment: Do you have a recent system state backup?

Comment: And this, folks, is why you have and test backups

Comment: I have a recent backup but I need to get to the VHDs that run Acronis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to connect the volume that the VM is on to another machine and pull it out. Then, you can transfer it to another Hyper-V server to get your AD up and running.

While the copy is happening, update your resume.

Then, you may have to reinstall/restore the physical host.

Comment: Resume updated. Luckily, the servers are used for my home development network. The vhds are on a raid 5 volume on the server. Sounds like I should do a clean install of 2008 R2 and copy off the AD backup instance.